# jquery css function not working on page refresh

Tags: jquery, css, image, height, width

I am trying to get the dimension ratio of an image using the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    aspectRatio = parseInt( $('img.sample_image').css('width') ) + ':' +
    parseInt( $('img.sample_image').css('height') ); 
    ...
```

This code works fine when the page loads.  However, sometimes when I refresh the page in Crome, using ctrl-R or the refresh button, the ratio is stored as 0:0.

How could I fix this?

Comment: try $(window).load(function(){

Comment: @Neo An explanation as to why would be nice... If the OP tries, and it works, they've learned nothing...

Comment: Why do you need to parseInt when you're just concatenating the result to a string `:`? That's probably your issue. Iff the css-width is '100px', that's probably parsing to 0.

Comment: @JuanMendes load is called when all assets are done loading, including images and ready is fired when the DOM is ready for interaction.

Comment: @Neo I know that, the OP doesn't. The other aspect is the fact that you can't get an image's dimensions before it's loaded. But if it's in the cache, it will be ready with the `$.ready` event. Hitting CTRL+R may cause the cache to be cleared and cause the problem again. I added an answer with a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead using:

```
$(window).load()
```

See the comparison of the two events here:

http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

```
$(window).load(function(){
    aspectRatio = parseInt( $('img.sample_image').css('width') ) + ':' +
    parseInt( $('img.sample_image').css('height') );
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your css('width') call is providing a string with units specified, and parseInt won't evaluate the way you expect it to.

In general I'd recommend going to the image itself, not its CSS, to grab the height and width:

```
var height = $('img.sample_image')[0].clientWidth;
```

so

```
var elem = $('img.sample_image')[0];
var aspectRatio = elem.clientWidth.toString() + ":" + elem.clientHeight.toString();
```

`[0]` grabs the first *dom element* from the jquery object.

**Alternatively**, use jquery's `.width()` and `.height()` functions instead of `.css()`:

```
var aspectRatio = $('img.sample_image').width().toString() + ':' + $('img.sample_image').height().toString()
```

Comment: I have not used [0] in jquery before, thanks for the tip!  I tested both our your methods and they do return the correct info, but there are still issues involving Chrome page refresh. The [0].clientWidth method does not always work when I refresh (50% success.)  The .width() method never works on refresh.

Answer (score 1):

- The `$.ready` event will fire as soon as the DOM is ready, not waiting for images to load.
- The `$.load` event will fire after all resources (such as CSS and images) have loaded

Therefore, your code is running before images have loaded (and therefore you can't know their size), but it works sometimes because they may have been cached. Hitting `Ctrl+R` may clear your cache and cause the problem again.

As others suggested, you should wait for the `$.load` event to make sure your image finished loading.